# execute raw python commands using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I wanted to execute raw mongo commands like (db.getUsers()) through the pymongo SDK. For example I have some js file which will contain only db.getUsers() in it . My python program needs to execute that command through establishing connection . I tried this db.command , db.runCommand but I'm not able to achieve that. After establishing the connection it should execute the mongo command whatever in the js file. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.getUsers()` is a shell helper script to the `usersInfo` command (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getUsers/)

> db.getUsers() wraps the usersInfo: 1 command.

You can run the `usersInfo` command using `db.command()` in pymongo with something like

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['admin']
command_result = db.command({'usersInfo': 1})

print(command_result)
```

Comment: That's only half the stack trace so can't really tell what's up.

Comment: Its working Belly thank you

Comment: So for all the python commands do we need to convert them into these Pymongo commands ? is there anyway I ca execute directly db.getUsers() directly , or something like show dbs directly from PyMongo sdk?

Comment: So you have to understand that when you are running db,getUsers and various other "admin" commands, these are just mongo shell helper scripts that wrap the more complicated db.command function. Just because you can run them at the shell does not mean the exact commands can be run in the various language APIs such as pymongo. But you can run the db.command equivalent as outlined in the answer. Hope this makes sense.